# Executing a script upon import in node js, without calling a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I am trying to import a typescript module that loads my environment variables. since the order of import and executions for my variables is important for my app, I want to refactor them from my `index.ts` file into another module. However, I don't want to call a function to run my script, but rather I want to execute them upon importing the module which I am doing right now with the `loadEnvVars()` function.

```js
// index.ts

import loadEnvVars from './settings';
**loadEnvVars();**
import app from './server';

app.run();
```

Instead of above I want:

```js
// index.ts
import loadEnvVars from './settings';
import app from './server';

app.run();
```

```js
// ./settings.ts

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';
const envVars = (): void => {
  dotenv.config({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV),
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
  });
};

export default envVars
```

I myself have come up with the following solution but I am not sure if this is a proper way of doing such imports:

```js
// index.ts

import './settings';
...
```

```js
// settings.ts

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

const envVars = (): void => {
  dotenv.config({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV),
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
  });
};

envVars();

export default envVars;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a bit cleaner by removing the function entirely, since it's no longer used, but called automatically:

```
// settings.ts

import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({
  path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV),
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
});

// remove this next line
// export default envVars;
```

That said - depending on `import` order leads to fragile code. It would be easy to mess up something by accidentally importing something else before importing `settings` that depends on the config already being set. If I were you, consider continuing to use the original code. Explicit execution dependency timelines are good.

Also note that imports are hoisted. Your code of

```
import loadEnvVars from './settings';
loadEnvVars();
import app from './server';
```

is equivalent to

```
import loadEnvVars from './settings';
import app from './server';
loadEnvVars();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part works and makes sense to me. The second part however doesn't work for me. The reason is that my `loadEnvVars` has my database information,  and within `app` i am calling those vars to connect to database. By moving `loadEnvVars` after `app` it fails at starting database. Would appreciate it if you can clarify on that, although my issue is solved with the first part

Comment: Also, if you can edit your answer for the following line, I can accept the answer: `import loadEnvVars from './settings';` this needs to be changed to `import  './settings';` since I removed those suggested lines and applied your suggested changes for `settings.ts`

Comment: I was only referring to your original code there - showing that imports are hoisted. I wasn't saying "use *this* code", I was saying "your original code is equivalent to..." for better understanding of how imports work. Your original `import './settings';` is just fine *if* you want to rely on the side-effect-only import